# How can I filter a resultset by a list from a table?

Tags: kql

Let's say I have a table that contains my favorite IDs. For instance:

```
let favoriteIds = datatable (identifier: double) [123, 234, 356, 789];
```

Then I have a gigantic table with a column called Id, and I want to filter to just the rows where Id matches one of the values in favoriteIds. Something like:

```
HugeTable | where favoriteIds contains Id
```

My problem is I always get an error - IIRC, it's the tabular expression cannot be found, or something similar.

**Question**: How am I supposed to filter a resultset by a list from a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`in()` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/in-cs-operator). For example:

```
HugeTable
| where id in(favoriteIds)
```